# How to control accessibility voiceover text for the SwiftUI Image

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

For the SwiftUI Image element, the voiceover template is seems "*accessibility label - image - image name*", e.g. for

```
var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "equal")
            .accessibilityLabel("my label")
    }
```

I am getting voiceover response "*my label image equal*".

Is it possible for voiceover to **only** say "my label", and not pronounce the "image equal" part?

Comment: Add `.accessibilityRemoveTraits(.isImage)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the element gets the focus, the default trait(link, button, label, etc) will be played after `accessibilityLabel` text. That's the reason it reads out as *"my label -> image"*

To add or remove the default trait following methods can be used :

- `.accessibilityAddTraits`
- `.accessibilityRemoveTraits`

**Example**

To recognize an image as a button:

Add `.isButton` trait and remove the `.isImage` trait, now VoiceOver can read the description of Image as *"my label -> button"*

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "equal")
            .accessibilityLabel("my label")
            .accessibilityAddTraits(.isButton)
            .accessibilityRemoveTraits(.isImage)
    }
}
```

> As an element can have multiple traits, remove the ones you don't want the voiceover to read.

Answer (score 1):

If your image is not used as a button and still want to accomplish this use,

```
Image(decorative: "equal")
```

This will stop the VoiceOver from reading the image name. And you can add or remove other traits as necessary.

Comment: decorative is a good choice for named assets, but in this case the OP has a systemImage (ie a SF Symbol).  Those need different handling.  To achieve the effect of removing the image entirely from VoiceOver, you can add the modifier                 .accessibility(hidden: true) to the Image

Comment: Once you add decorative to any image, this will not allow VoiceOver to focus on this element, no matter what modifiers you add to this after

Answer (score 1):

Try using Labels instead of images:

```
Label("My Label", systemImage: "equal")
```

Accessibility Voiceover will just read the label "equal", and not mention 'image'.

You can control what appears onscreen using the
`.labelStyle` modifier: e.g.

```
.labelStyle(.iconOnly)
```

You will note that 'accessibility' is not mentioned here; we are just using idiomatic SwiftUI; and yet it works just as well for accessibility as more complex answers.

Answer (score 1):

To have an image announce its accessibility label only, you can do this:

`Image("equal").accessibilityLabel(Text("my label")) .accessibilityRemoveTraits(.isImage)`

Comment: how is your answer different from accepted answer?

Comment: @timbretimbre the accepted answer mentions button and no where in the original question does it mention that this is an image that is actionable